# Python - How to compare user input to dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, input, tkinter

I've recently began learning Python, and I'm trying to write a simple Q&A program. I want the user to be able to insert input and have it be compared to keys in a dictionary, and whichever key that has the most words in common with the question will be activated, and the answer will be printed. Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk 
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(666, 666))
var = StringVar()
vara = StringVar()

resp = {'What programming language was this written in?': 'This program was written using Python 3.5. Python is a widely used high-level, general-purpose, dynamic programming language. Its syntax enables programmers to write code in fewer lines than more complex languages like Java and C++.', 'Who invented computer programming?': 'Charles Babbage is universally accepted as the father of computer programming due to his creation of the analytical engine. While computers were not created until a century beyond his invention, the analytical engine used an identical concept for input/output commands.', 'What coding language was used to create Windows OS?': 'Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 operate on C++ and C# almost exclusively. Because these are lower-level languages, the programmer has greater control over the computer itself, enabling them to do many amazing things.'}


label = Message( root, textvariable=var,      relief=RAISED)
labelfont = ('times', 20, 'bold')

def callback():

    parabel = Tk()
    parabel.minsize(600, 400)
    parabel.maxsize(600,400)
    parabel.title("BonneyBot")

    pLabel = Label(parabel, text = "Welcome to     BonneyBot.").pack(side = TOP)
    pLabel1 = Label(parabel, text = "Ask a question about programming!").pack()
    pEntry1 = ttk.Entry(parabel, textvariable = vara)
    pEntry1.pack(side='top')

    def response():
        if pEntry1.get() in resp.keys():
            messagebox.showinfo('file',  resp[pEntry1.get()])
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning('error', 'I did not understand the question. Please ask again.')



    ttk.Button(parabel, text = "ASK AWAY!",     command=response).pack()




widget = Label(root, text="Welcome to my graduation project!\n This is a simple Q&A program created\n by Devin intended to assist individuals\n curious about computer programming.\n Click start to begin!")
widget.config(bg='lightblue', fg='red')
widget.config(font=labelfont)
widget.config(height=3, width=20)
widget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
var.set("Let's get started!")


MyButton1 = Button(root, text="START", command=callback)
MyButton1.pack()



label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

What could I add to compare the words in common with the user input with the keys in the dictionary? I'm pretty sure that I would use a for loop to compare the common words with each key to print the value, but I'm uncertain about how to do this. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, `pEntry1.get()` returns the text that the user inputted ?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: I remember doing something similar when I learned basic JavaScript on CodeAcademy (what a noob, right? :P) when I compared numbers I typed in to entries in a phone book, but I don't remember how to do this. What I want to do is fairly similar to that.

Comment: Then your if statement in the `response` function is already checking if any part of the user input is present in any of the keys of the dictionary `resp`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Essentially, but the response function only activates if the user input inserts a key verbatim. However, I want the user input to be compared to each key so the user can get a response without typing the entire key... for example, if the user types "Who invented" then I want the corresponding value to be printed for "Who invented computer programming." Does that help?

Comment: In that case you need to save the value returned by `pEntry1.get()` in a variable and compare it against the keys. I'll post an answer with an example

Comment: Alright, that would be very helpful! Thanks a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is save the result of `pEntry1.get()` in a variable so you can compare it with each key present in the dictionary.

```
user_input = pEntry1.get()

for question in resp.keys():
    if user_input in question:
        messagebox.showinfo('file', resp[question])
....
```

This will check if any part of the user input is in any of the keys in the `resp` dictionary.

PS: you should look into pep8 as a style guide and use more variables. For example `pEntry1.get()` is called a couple of times and it can be stored in a variable before the `if` statement as shown in the example.

Comment: That definitely helps, but now for some reason the else statement is activated even when the conditions are met for the if statement. I inserted the for loop into the if/then statement.